# How to tell a position with a velocity is going inwards or outwards of a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have a point inside a rectangle. This point has a velocity vector.
So I have a position vector and a velocity vector.
I want to figure out when the point updates it's position based on velocity, would it go outside of the rectangle from the closest edge of the rectangle to the point.

That is, if the point is going inwards, or outwards of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is the cross product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Let's say you have an edge `AB` and a point `C`, then you can look at the sign of `AB ^ BC`

You will need to test if positive sign mean in or out, and negative sign will be the other.

But you will have to be consistent in your point ordering because `AB ^ BC = - BC ^ 
AB`

Comment: and how do I find the closest edge AB given a position vector inside the rectangle?

Comment: @eguneys you could just check against each one of your edges, but note that if you work only with axis aligned rectangle then you checking for a point inside is trivial